# $.post inside html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I have two functions:

Number One

```
html2canvas($("#screenshot"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $('.ha').append(canvas);
  }
});
```

Number Two

```
$.post("save.php",{ xcv : canvas }, function(data){
  if (data == 1)
  {
    $('.cropped').empty();
    $('.cropped').append('<img src="' + data + '">');
    $('.cropped').append('<h2>Is this okay?</h2>');
  }
  else
  {
    alert(theCanvas);
  }
});
```

Function Number one just takes a screenshot of the div-container "screenshot" and shows it in the div-class "ha". Function number two just should give the canvas to a php file which will transform the canvas into a pyhsical file. If this was successful the php-file will return a "1" and post the picture on the page because "data" keeps the filename. I tried something like this:

```
html2canvas($("#screenshot"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $('.ha').append(canvas);

    $.post("save.php",{ xcv : canvas }, function(data)
    {
      if (data == 1)
      {
        $('.cropped').empty();
        $('.cropped').append('<img src="' + data + '">');
        $('.cropped').append('<h2>Is this okay?</h2>');
      }
      else
      {
        alert(theCanvas);
      }
    });

    }
});
```

But its not working. The thing is that if i use the both functions seperatly they are working perfectly fine.

The whole thing looks like this:

```
$('#btnCrop').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas($("#screenshot"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $.post("save.php",{ xcv : canvas }, function(data)
            {
                if (data != '')
                {
                    $('.cropped').empty();
                    $('.cropped').append('<img src="' + data + '">');
                    $('.cropped').append('<h2>Is this okay?</h2>');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });

    }
    });

})
```

and here the screenshot after i pushed the button

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Hey, means it does not send anything to the "save.php". I tracked the http traffic, nothing is coming through.

Comment: Open browser dev kit, and look at network tab - after u send ajax - what do u see there, and show to us

Comment: In `Number Two`, what is `canvas`? Is it really the same as `onrendered: function(canvas) {...}` parameter?

Comment: Hey A. Wolff, thank you very much for your question! That made me figure out the solution, I was under the impression i get a base64 string from the "canvas" but i didnt. I just needed to add a var x = canvas.toDataURL(); and work with "x" and not "canvas", no its working perfectly fine. THank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Wolff, thank you very much for your question! That made me figure out the solution, I was under the impression i get a base64 string from the "canvas" but i didnt. I just needed to add a

```
var x = canvas.toDataURL();
```

and work with "x" and not "canvas", no its working perfectly fine. So the whole thing looks like this:

```
$('#btnCrop').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas($("#screenshot"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var x = canvas.toDataURL();

            $.post("save.php",{ xcv : x }, function(data)
            {
                if (data != '')
                {
                    $('.cropped').empty();
                    $('.cropped').append('<img src="' + data + '">');
                    $('.cropped').append('<h2>Is this okay?</h2>');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(theCanvas);
                }
            });

    }
    });

})
```

Thank you again!